# load react route in another electron window

Tags: electron, react-router-dom, electron-react-boilerplate

I am using hashrouter with electron-react-boilerplate. I noticed that the new window browser started showing white screen, thus, can't find any url to load after the app is packaged.

My route is configured this way

```
import { Route, Routes, HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" index element={<LoaderScreen />} />
        <Route path="expired" index element={<ExpiredPage />} />
        <Route path="live" element={<LiveScreen />} />
        <Route key={1} path="/app/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route key={1} index element={<FreeScreen />} />
          <Route key={1} path="simple" element={<FreeScreen />} />
          <Route key={3} path="schedule" element={<PaidScreen />} />
          <Route key={5} path="settings" element={<SettingsScreen />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Any this is the function that resolves the url path

```
export function resolveHtmlPath(htmlFileName: string) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
    const url = new URL(`http://localhost:${port}`);
    url.pathname = htmlFileName;
    return url.href;
  }
  return `file://${path.resolve(__dirname, '../renderer/', htmlFileName)}`;
}
```

I need to load the component/route from main.ts into a separate window using hashrouter.Thanking you in advance

These are things that I have tried. This line of code loads the window when the development server is started `liveWindow?.loadURL('http://localhost:1212#/app/settings')`
and since the package app does not run a server, I tried using this `liveWindow?.webContents.loadURL(resolveHtmlPath('index.html#/app/settings'))`. I could still not get the route loaded.

I have also tried this `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html#/live')}`); and `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html#/live')}`);

Comment: What about just ```liveWindow?.webContents.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`)```? The app and router are served and running from root. With this change does your app at least load and run in the electron container? You mention that is "started showing white screen"... does this mean you had something that was working previously? If so, can you [edit] to include that code for comparison to what you are trying to use now?

Comment: Yes, the app worked as intended when it was running with the development server 'localhost:1212' and same setup doesn't work after app is packaged. I have tried the above code in your comment before posting.

Comment: Are you able to open the chrome dev-tools on the device running the non-development build to see if there are any errors or further debugging details you can explore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little adjustment to the resolveHtmlPath function.

```
export function resolveHtmlPath(htmlFileName: string, hash?: string) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
    const url = new URL(`http://localhost:${port}`);
    url.pathname = htmlFileName;
    return url.href;
  }
  // Add hash here (if provided)
  return `file://${path.resolve(__dirname, '../renderer/', htmlFileName)}${
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-template
    hash ? '#' + hash : ''
  }`;
}
```

So I could do the url this way;

```
liveWindow?.webContents.loadURL(resolveHtmlPath('index.html', 'live'))
```